# Is there a way to set Other Linker flags to Theos Logos Tweak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, makefile, jailbreak, theos

Hi Does anyone know how to set -ObjC as **Other linker flag** for logos tweak? Currently I'm using,

> MyTest_LDFLAGS = -lsqlite3 -ObjC

or

```
MyTest_LDFLAGS = -lsqlite3 -lObjC
```

Answer (score 2):

Never after several hours of researching and reading the documentation I figured it out. Its simple, you need to pass the other linker flags as an command line argument.

> user-macbook:$ make LDFLAGS=-ObjC

here is the complete link, http://uv.howett.net/ipf.html

Comment: I wish you all the karma in the world